create uefi bootable usb stick, no ISO
I'm trying to convert a old trusty bootable USB stick from MBR to UEFI. Got everything set up, but when I try to boot it I get msg: "ALERT! LABEL=... does not exist." The label is fine.  Last time I had a similar problem it turned out to be the initrd.img -- when I copied the kernel and the initrd from a Debian install USB, it booted fine. But when I copy the kernel and initrd from my HDD, I get the above error.  I'd copy from the install stick again, but it's a couple of upgrades out of date.  How can I get this fixed?  I suspect I need to rebuild the initrd on the stick, but obviously I don't want to touch the working initrd on my HDD.  Note, I boot using rEFInd, which sees the stick ok, and starts to boot it, but again, there's that 'ALERT! ...'

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775552/making-a-debian-usb-wrong-initrd-img ... that's most of the answer.
